# How to navigate between different nested stacks in react navigation without changing the state of bottom navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab

**Current Behavior**

My react-native application consists of a BottomTabNavigator that contains several StackNavigators. A simplified example of my structure looks like this

BottomTab

Tab 1 (default screen A)

```
Stack

    Screen A

    Screen B
```

Tab 2 (default screen D)

```
Stack

    Screen C

    Screen D
```

Tab 3 (default screen E)

```
Stack

    Screen E

    Screen F
```

From the Bottom Tab 1, Screen A. I need to navigate Screen C in Bottom Tab 2. I was done this by using nested navigation.

```
navigation.navigate('Tab 2', { screen: 'Screen C' });
```

When I navigate screens in tab 1, or tab 3, and press Tab 2, application loading screen C. But my default screen for Bottom Tab 2 is screen D.

**My problem is**:
How can I navigate to default screen of tab 2 (screen D) when I navigating to bottom Tab 2. The problem occurred after the above mentioned nested navigation. Any other way to navigate or any other suggestions ?